# How to get MS Access DB Author, Last Modified Date, Last Modified By etc using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I am trying to get all the properties of MS Access DB using vb.net like Author, Last Modified Date, Last Modified By etc..

Answer (score 2):

These are extended properties. I think that this thread [Read/Write 'Extended' file properties (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220097/readwrite-extended-file-properties-c) will help. It includes a vb,net example.

Owner may be of more interest than Author for Access databases.

You may wish to read [How to ask a question](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/555375/en-us)