# retrieving executable information

Tags: c#, .net, shell

When you right-click an .exe file, you can see various details, such as file description.

I'm looking for way to retrieve that data programmatically (preferably, from C#).

(Program's name, program's description, Vendor's name, Vendor's site etc)

[image]

Comment: Very similar to this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/220097/read-write-extended-file-properties-c. You could probably find some ideas there

Comment: (@all: I'm not 100% sure they are the same thing, but if you want me to merge these two questions, please let me know)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can get a lot (but not all) of this via [`FileVersionInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.fileversioninfo_properties.aspx):

```
    FileVersionInfo fvi = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(path);
    string company = fvi.CompanyName;
    string productName = fvi.ProductName;
    string productVer = fvi.ProductVersion;
    // etc
```