# How to set file comment in c#

Tags: c#, filesystems

How to set any file comment, author information from c#?

Comment: Maybe this related question will be of help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/220097/read-write-extended-file-properties-c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### New Answer

You may want to check out [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220097/read-write-extended-file-properties-c), which details what you're trying to do (I think).

#### Olde Answer

[Use XML Comments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b2s063f7.aspx).

The [list of tags](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ast78ax.aspx) doesn't explicitly include `author`, but you can add it.

Example:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Example Summary of method
    /// </summary>
    /// <author>
    /// George Stocker
    /// </author>
    /// <date>
    /// 9/28/2009
    /// </date>
    static void Authorstuff()
    {
         //method stuff here  
    }
```

Comment: He's after setting comments on arbitrary files, I believe, not C# source code. No down-vote though, since the question wasn't immediately clear without looking at the tags.