# Read/Write Info in File Details tab - Windows/File Explorer

Tags: c#, .net, winapi

When you Right-click a file in Windows/File Explorer > Properties > Details, you get a whole lot of useful information about that file.

How can we programmatically access that information in C#?

The only *somewhat* (no offense) answer I've come across after months of searching for a solution is [How do I get details from File Properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4074565/how-do-i-get-details-from-file-properties) - but that answer was written **4** years ago. There has to be a better way to achieve this goal by now, right?

Comment: Did  you also see the answered duplicate that it links too?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/220097/read-write-extended-file-properties-c/2096315#2096315

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use FileInfo Class.

```
FileInfo oFileInfo = new FileInfo(strFilename);
```

Now, with `oFileInfo` object, you can access file properties.

Comment: Even File Properties such as Owner, Album Artist, Album, Genre, Length, Publisher, Composers, or Subtitle, Copyright? I use FileInfo all the time and I've never seen that many properties available.

Comment: Then you have to use shell32.dll. See example here. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5036/ID-Tag-Reader-Using-Shell-Functions

Comment: Here is another nice example. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7987/Retrieve-detailed-information-of-a-File