# Change the author name of power point file

Tags: php, ms-office, powerpoint, flexbuilder

Can I change the author of a power point file using PHP or any other language ?

Comment: Currently I used both  Linux and Windows server.I want to change the author name of power point file while uploading to that server.For uploading I am using Php code in server.

Comment: try this.. here is a way to modify author using C#.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5337683/how-to-set-extended-file-properties

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it appears that [PHPPowerPoint](http://phppowerpoint.codeplex.com/) has the ability to open and save ppt and pptx documents, and can manipulate document metadata.

Comment: PHPPowerPoint have any sdk for that?

Comment: SDK? You can just download PHPPowerpoint classes and reference them in your code. Just like any other PHP file.

Comment: Thanks...I will try and inform you later.

Answer (score 0):

You can change from menu Prepare/ Properties