# Powershell - Set 'title' in photo file using Taglib-sharp not working

Tags: powershell, attributes, photo, taglib-sharp

I'm trying to change the 'title' (extended file attribute) in multiple photos using Taglib-Sharp in Powershell.
While it works fine for most, it doesn't for certain photos. So far from my initial testing it appears to not work with Olympus produced JPEG's or JPEG's without any EXIF info in them at all.

I'm using TagLib-Sharp 2.1.0.0, I've tried older version's too.

This is my code:

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom( ("c:\taglib-sharp.dll") )
$media = [TagLib.File]::Create("C:\temp\photo.jpg")
$media.ImageTag.Title = "Test Title"
$media.save()
```

This is the error I get:

```
PS C:\Users\tris> C:\Write_tag_taglib-sharp.ps1

GAC    Version        Location                                                         
---    -------        --------                                                         
False  v2.0.50727     c:\taglib-sharp.dll                                              
Exception calling "Save" with "0" argument(s): "File not writeable. Corrupt metadata?"
At C:\Write_tag_taglib-sharp.ps1:4 char:1
+ $media.save()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException
```

The photos all appear fine and I can manually set the `TITLE` without issue in Windows Explorer.

I've no prior experience in this area and am new to Powershell - can anyone help?

Comment: Just a guess, but are you running as a normal user? Storing files outside personal folders requires elevated priviligies. To test this, run powershell as admin or try with a file stored on your desktop.

Comment: Hi - thanks for the comment. I'm running it as Administrator. It makes no difference if I run the script and place the DLL in the c:\temp folder where the photo is.

Comment: Not familiar with taglib, but if you only need to modify jpeg, png (specific formats), you can check out the example on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapmetadata.getquery.aspx and replace the png decoder with the appropiate, ex. `System.Windows.Media.Imaging.JpegBitmapDecoder`

Comment: Does not sound like a issue with powershell, but with taglib-sharp. Is the file readonly? Try $media.CorruptionReasons before calling Save and see what the reasons are.

Comment: Hi Lars - the file is not read only. I ran the command above and it brings back `Size of entries exceeds possible data size`

Comment: Sounds like a corrupt EXIF structure or a bug in taglib-sharp