# VBA Write file tags from excel

Tags: excel, vba, tags

I have some code that can make a list of files in folder and get their tags:

```vb
Option explicit

'Declare variables
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim i As Long
Dim FolderPath As String
Dim objShell, objFolder, objFolderItem As Object
Dim FSO, oFolder, oFile As Object
 
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") 'Set sheet name

Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.ClearContents
ws.Range("A1:D1").Value = Array("FileName", "Tags", "Subgroup", "Group")

Set FSO = CreateObject("scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set oFolder = FSO.GetFolder(FolderLocation_TextBox.Value)

i = 2 'First row to print result

For Each oFile In oFolder.Files

'If any attribute is not retrievable ignore and continue
On Error Resume Next
    Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace(oFolder.Path)
    Set objFolderItem = objFolder.ParseName(oFile.Name)
    
    ws.Cells(i, 1) = oFile.Name
    ws.Cells(i, 2).Value = objFolder.GetDetailsOf(objFolderItem, 18) 'Tags
    ws.Cells(i, 5).Value = objFolder.GetDetailsOf(objFolderItem, 277)   'Description
    i = i + 1
On Error Resume Next
Next
```

And now I'm wondering how to write them to those files I get in the list. I am basically trying to write tags from excel.

I have a full filename in column `A` and a string I'm trying to write as a tag to each file is in column `B`.
The address of the folder is in the value of a textbox: `UserForm_Tag.FolderLocation_TextBox.value`.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67862172/9808063) is not working? ..  try replacing `FSO.GetFolder(FolderLocation_TextBox.Value)` with `FSO.GetFolder(UserForm_Tag.FolderLocation_TextBox.value)`

Comment: It is working, friend! I can get the tags, but now I need to write them back, because some files may not have a tag and I have a code that composes a correct tag for each separate file in column B, but now I am looking for a way to write them from excel to each files meta data. So I have a list of file names in "A" and tags in "B" and files location in a textbox. I am looking to write thsoe values from column B to corresponding files mentioned in column "A", you know?

Comment: ohhh. Got it wrong.

Comment: Probably better to tag PowerShell here .. Refer [this](https://abdus.dev/posts/powershell-file-metadata-guide/) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16638570/powershell-how-to-set-title-in-extended-file-properties)

Comment: Potentially helpful discussion here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35451540/extracting-windows-file-properties-custom-properties-c-sharp/35548859#35548859

Comment: I agree with other users. It probably better to change program language to write to files. VBA have quite a lot of limitations :(. The few working solutions I have seen seem to be using DSO, but it seem to be some work to make it up and running. The closest seem to be [Set file external properties using VBA?](https://www.accessforums.net/showthread.php?t=79278) and [Setting extended property values for external files using VBA](https://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/threads/setting-extended-property-values-for-external-files-using-vba.299228/).

Comment: I am clueless in any other language

Comment: Thanks, friend! Not really sure how to test it tho

Comment: There's a set of [Workbook.BuiltindocumentProperties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.builtindocumentproperties) you can change via VBA. You can also add custom property to [CustomDocumentProperties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.customdocumentproperties). Is that what you want? Note: built-in properties are displayed in file properties (file explorer).

Comment: Yes but how do I write the property from excel?

Answer (score 1):

> There's a set of Workbook.BuiltindocumentProperties you can change via
> VBA. You can also add custom property to CustomDocumentProperties. Is
> that what you want? Note: built-in properties are displayed in file
> properties (file explorer). – Maciej Los ... hours ago
>
> Yes but how do I write the property from excel? – Eduards ... hours ago

Well...

I'm pretty sure it's **impossible** to change extended file properties via standard VBA methods. I have seen ActiveX object, which can do that, for example: in the answer to the question [How can I change extended file properties using vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16989882/how-can-i-change-extended-file-properties-using-vba), user [jac](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17776/jac) do recommend to use `dsofile.dll`.

**Note:** *this library is limited to 32bit WinOS*, see: [64 Bit Application Cannot Use DSOfile](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1118708/Bit-Application-Cannot-Use-DSOfile). More details about `dsofile.dll` you'll find here: [How to set file details using VBA](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/19ecbf77-0f6b-4fef-905c-283db70a92d4/how-to-set-file-details-using-vba). The most important information is:

> With VBA (DSOFile) you can only set basic file properties and only on
> NTFS. Microsoft has discontinued the practice of storing file
> properties in the secondary NTFS stream (introduced with Windows
> Vista) as properties saved on those streams do not travel with the
> file when the file is send as attachment or stored on USB disk that is
> FAT32 not NTFS.

As i mentioned in the comment to the question, if you want to change basic (most common used) extended file property **for Excel/Word file**, i'd suggest to use  [BuiltinDocumentProperties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.builtindocumentproperties). Some built-in properties correspond to [extended file properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/tn-archive/ee176615(v=technet.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN). For example:

| BuiltinDocumentProperty | Extended Property (EP) | EP Index |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Title | Title | 10 |
| Subject | Subject | 11 |
| Author | Author | 9 |
| Comments | Comments | 14 |
| Creation Date | Date created | 4 |
| Category | Category | 12 |
| Company | Company | 30 |
| and so on... |  |  |

To enumerate all built-in properties:

```
Sub GetBuiltinProperties()
    Dim wsh As Worksheet, bdc As DocumentProperty
    Dim i As Long
    
    Set wsh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2)
    On Error Resume Next
    i = 2
    For Each bdc In ThisWorkbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties
        wsh.Range("A" & i) = bdc.Name
        wsh.Range("B" & i) = bdc.Value
        i = i + 1
    Next
    Set wsh = Nothing

End Sub
```

To set built-in property:

```
Sub SetBuiltinProperties()

    With ThisWorkbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties
        .Item("Keywords") = "My custom tag"
        .Item("Comments") = "My custom description"
    End With

End Sub
```

So... If you want to change built-in property for specific workbook, you have to:

- open it,
- chage/set built-in property,
- save it,
- and close it.

Comment: Thanks! I am trying to set the tags of the files in the list that I get from the folder and not the tag of the workbook.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. In this case, you have to use `dsofile.dll`, even if the use of it is very limited.

Comment: Yeah, like explained in the OP I basically am taking a folder address and making a list in excel (I also get a list of tags for each file). Then I am concatenating a tags string if they are not already present for a particular file, and now I need to write those tags back to those files in the list.