# modify files sent date using c#.net

Tags: c#, outlook

here is what i want to do
Step I: I have an .eml file
[image: emlfile]

Step II: I want to change files Date sent value using C#.net

[image]

If you are unable to see this column on your pc follow these steps.
[image: right click on header column and click on more option]

[image: check date sent checkbox and click on ok]

Comment: I edited the tags of your question, because I think its not related to asp.net, but rather to outlook.

Comment: thanks EFrank... actually i want to modify above mention date using C#

Comment: is there any confusion in my question??

Answer (score 0):

See the link [How to SET extended file properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5337683/how-to-set-extended-file-properties)

This will defiantly help you. You will need to add dsofile.dll and OleDocumentPropertiesClass

Comment: thanks.. is there any other solution.. i mean in .net framework to access extended properties???

Comment: i had tried using this DLL but it doesn't show this(mentioned in diagram) property of the file.