# Reading/Writing metadata of audio/video files

Tags: c#, taglib-sharp

I need some help in reading/writing meta data inforamation of audio/vido file. I have searched alot but not find anything thing helpful.  Taglib sharp is an open source library that provide help in reading/writing metadata. Using tag lib i'm able to edit some of values but not all like.

```
TagLib.File videoFile = TagLib.File.Create("test.mp4");
videoFile.Tag.Title = "Test";
videoFile.Tag.Comment = "Nothing";
```

but i'm unable to edit following properties like Author url, producers etc. How i edit these properties ??

Comment: I think the answer is given here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5337683/how-to-set-extended-file-properties

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've never done this for video files before but I have for mp3 files.  You can get access to those frames like this:

```
TagLib.File file = TagLib.File.Create(mp3FileName);
file.Tag.Title = "some title"; // you've got this
TagLib.Id3v2.Tag tag = (TagLib.Id3v2.Tag)file.GetTag(TagTypes.Id3v2);
tag.SetTextFrame("WOAR", "some url"); // WOAR = Official artist/performer webpage
file.Save();
```

You can find a list of the text frame identifiers at Wikipedia:
[ID3v2 Frame Specification (Version 2.3)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Id3#ID3v2_Frame_Specification_.28Version_2.3.29)

I don't know if video files give you the same range of frames that ID3 does, though notice that Wikipedia also says ([Implementation in non-mp3s and alternatives](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Id3#Implementation_in_non-mp3s_and_alternatives))

> MP4 also allows the embedding of an ID3 tag, and this is widely supported.

So I would guess this also works for mp4 files like you're trying.

Comment: Thanks i will check it and return to you if there is any issue.

Comment: Using mp4 file, id3v2 tag always return null.

Comment: What about another TagType, like TagType.Id3v1?

Comment: Id3v1 does not contain SetTextFrame fucntion.

Comment: mp4 files contain tagType Apple no Id3v2 and Id3v1

Comment: @MuhammadUmar see my answer. Hope it will work for you.

Answer (score 5):

You will need to use AppleTag. This will work. For mp4 file you have to write value into dashbox. Like this:

```
TagLib.File videoFile = TagLib.File.Create("test.mp4");
TagLib.Mpeg4.AppleTag customTag = (TagLib.Mpeg4.AppleTag)f.GetTag(TagLib.TagTypes.Apple);
customTag.SetDashBox("Producer","Producer1", "value");
f.Save();
f.Dispose();
```

And you can get the value like this:

```
var tokenValue = customTag.GetDashBox("Producer", "Producer1");
```

Comment: It is working fine for mp4 files. You saved my day, thanks