# How to display assembly attributes in C# Binary

Tags: c#, .net-assembly

I have created a project. In the `AssemblyInfo.cs` file I have set values to the attributes as under:

[image]

When I check this in the `AssemblyInformation button`, I get to see correct details

[image]

However I build the project and check in the generated binary `properties window`, I do not see the value I had set. For example: See value of **Description**

[image]

- Then from where are these values being picked up ?
- Can I change them ? If yes, how ?
- Can I add new attributes of my own ?

I googled and found below link which tells me that it cannot be done, is it true ?

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d4d95113-4fa7-49af-bcdd-8960d79b1ba3/adding-a-custom-field-to-assembly-information-in-visual-c-project-for-windows-7?forum=csharpgeneral

Comment: I think this is the one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5337683/how-to-set-extended-file-properties