# accessing and manipulating file properties with programming in windows 10

Tags: c#, windows, file

I'm working on accessing and manipulating file properties in windows 10.

following images shows properties of two files.

[[image: 1]]

as yo can see, those file have different properties set.
and I'm working on add some extended properties. I referred to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5337683/how-to-set-extended-file-properties) and I tried with this, but failed with HRESULT... some error - unable to set property. I think those nuget are quite outdated and they do not work well, though reading properties work well. actually, the website that is written in `Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack-Shell` nuget is deprecated. :(...

Is there any approach to add some property to file? I googled a lot, but those are not available now in current version of windows 10. I can read property but can't write property.

I'll appreciate if you suggest a way that works in `C#` .net framework solution(except `UWP`- just `Console` and `WPF`). but if there are only a way raw `C` language based-API, then don't hesitate to tell me. I'm going to use it, anyway.

### Added

Microsoft Shell Controls And Automation also does not work.
[msdn for Shell control and automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/bb776890(v%3Dvs.85))

Comment: What kind of files are you willing to edit? I recently managed to edit some meta-data information of some kind of files like .mp3 .png, ...  with an open source library called [tag-lib sharp](https://github.com/mono/taglib-sharp). Watching its implementation I see that each kind of file has its own internal structure so you would have to build a customized functionality to edit each one.

Comment: Thx, @OscarMartinez. I'm working on company save file -Company where I work- . I have plenty of words to say about company works. But shortly, we are using just xml type documentation for saving user who use our application work. you can just think `xml` exetension file. Thank you for sharing information but TagLib does not support xml file. But your suggestion give me positive sight to my work. Thank you.