# Is there any Plugin compatible to unity that allows me to inscribe meta data into a file?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, plugins

I'm trying to manipulate the meta data of an Image, so i can compress and decompress it without losing information, I can already read the image meta data, but I can't actually edit them.

I found this similar question:
[How to set extended file properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5337683/how-to-set-extended-file-properties/5338133#5338133)  But it doesn't seem to work today, as it is pretty old.

Edit:
The project is for IOS and Android.

Comment: Not sure if this helps but according to [the Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/advanced/how-to-read-image-metadata?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) GDI+ should allow for both reading existing metadata and writing new metadata to image files.

Comment: Hey thanks for this info. I'm struggling to make it compile, it seems like the namespaces that this script needs is "System.Drawing.Imaging", and "System.Drawing.Bitmap", but my script don't seem to recognize them? Am I missing anything?

Unity just gives me an error "[Script path] error CS0234: The type or namespace name [Bitmap or Imaging] does not exist in the namespace 'System.Drawing' (are you missing an assembly reference?)".

Comment: You may need to add the `System.Drawing.Common` NuGet package to your project, as that's where types such as `Bitmap` are defined (`Bitmap` is part of the Windows-only .net full framework, but when using .net core it's one of the things which has been moved out into a separate package)

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer, installing the NuGet package made it found the namespaces, but it was not compatible with unity and mobile.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to use SharpZipLib in unity: https://www.nuget.org/packages/SharpZipLib/
and compress the image to a zip:

```
using System.IO.Compression;

private string CompressImage(string picturePersistentPath)
{
    string pictureCompressedPath = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, "Compressed.zip");
        
    using FileStream originalFileStream = File.Open(picturePersistentPath, FileMode.Open);
    using FileStream compressedFileStream = File.Create(pictureCompressedPath);
    using var compressor = new GZipStream(compressedFileStream, CompressionMode.Compress);
    originalFileStream.CopyTo(compressor);

    return pictureCompressedPath;
}
```