# Can Unity3d create a file with metadata ? (or edit a file metadata)

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine

Is it possible in unity3d (v2020) to edit a file's Metadata on the disk (in my case it would be a VIDEO)?

Let's say i want to put some infos in 'Comments' field for example.
Is this possible?
For now i'm using File.WriteAllText in system.io but I need to pass some infos as metadata.

Comment: What’s stopping you so far? What code do you have how didn’t it work. What else have you tried?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set extended file properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5337683/how-to-set-extended-file-properties)