# How to know if a *.lnk file link to something or not

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

How to know if a *.lnk file link to something or not. How can I achieve that in C#?

Comment: Perhaps check the file exists on the link property path?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/139010/how-to-resolve-a-lnk-in-c-sharp and then use the appropriate file.exists to see if it exists.

Comment: A link always links to something, do you mean that you want to check if that something is currently reachable?

Comment: I want to know if a lnk file link to something or not. If not, I want to delete them.

Answer (score 0):

1. Get the `Link Target` [Getting specific file attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6235081/getting-specific-file-attributes)
2. Check the file from `Link Target Path` if exist using the [File.Exists](http://www.dotnetperls.com/file-exists)

> ```
> class Program
> {
>     [STAThread]
>     static void Main()
>     {
>         List<string> arrHeaders = new List<string>();
>
>         Shell32.Shell shell = new Shell32.Shell();
>         Shell32.Folder objFolder;
>
>         objFolder = shell.NameSpace(@"D:\shortcuts");
>
>         for (int i = 0; i < short.MaxValue; i++)
>         {
>             string header = objFolder.GetDetailsOf(null, i);
>             if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(header))
>                 break;
>             arrHeaders.Add(header);
>         }
>
>         foreach (Shell32.FolderItem2 item in objFolder.Items())
>         {
>             for (int i = 0; i < arrHeaders.Count; i++)
>             {
>                 //Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}: {2}", i, arrHeaders[i], objFolder.GetDetailsOf(item, i));
>                 if (arrHeaders[i] == "Link target")
>                 {
>                     var getPath = objFolder.GetDetailsOf(item, i);
>                     Console.WriteLine("{0}", getPath);
>                     if (File.Exists(getPath))
>                     {
>                         Console.WriteLine("The file exists.");
>                     }
>                     else
>                     {
>                         Console.WriteLine("File not exist");
>                         //Do stuff to delete
>                     }
>                 }
>             }
>         }
>         Console.ReadLine();
>     }
> }
> ```