# vb.net read dimensions (video height & width) from specific file

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, properties, dimension

okay so i'm working with visual studio 2010.

I need to read out the resolution from a MPEG file. So that would be the video width en height.

I think I need to create a button linked to an openfiledialog.show(), and then get a property from the specified file, by passing it on to a function.

My question: Does vb.net has build-in methods to gather the property of a file? Or does one know a free com component that does it for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think MPG files have detailed meta data embedded in them. However, have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220097/read-write-extended-file-properties-c) which explains how to get extended data from the tags stored with the file. If you right-click on the video file...`Properties`...`Details`, the file may have its `Frame Width` and `Frame Height` information filled in. You can extract this information, using the details from the link, to get the relevant information.

Comment: I tried using the link you gave, however, the information outputted by this function is not complete. In the property's windows of my mpeg file i clearly see the dimensions. The outputef file however gives this:
0 Name: Movie2
1 Size: 1,39 GB
2 Item type: Movie Clip
3 Date modified: 10/06/2011 0:48
4 Date created: 11/06/2011 16:51
5 Date accessed: 11/06/2011 16:51
6 Attributes: A
7 Offline status: 
8 Offline availability: 
9 Perceived type: Video
10 Owner: MYCOMPUTER
11 Kind: Video
12 Date taken: 
13 Contributing artists: 
14 Album: 
15 Year: 
16 Genre:

Comment: 17 Conductors: 
18 Tags: 
19 Rating: Unrated
20 Authors: 
21 Title: 
22 Subject: 
23 Categories: 
24 Comments: 
25 Copyright: 
26 #: 
27 Length: 00:37:49
28 Bit rate: ‎192kbps
29 Protected: 
30 Camera model: 
31 Dimensions: 
32 Camera maker: 
33 Company: 
34 File description:

Comment: As you can see; item 32: Dimensions remains empty

Comment: Is more information provided if you follow the advice in the comments about increasing the `arrHeaders` size?

Comment: so far only these items look helpfull, but they also remain empty:
160 Bit depth: 161 Horizontal resolution: 162 Width: 163 Vertical resolution: 164 Height:

Comment: okay i found it, it was somewhere in the range 250-300 that i saw the width and heigt vallues passing by. Thanks for your help man!