# C#: How to read information in File summary tab?

Tags: c#, .net, file, summary

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Read/Write 'Extended' file properties (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220097/read-write-extended-file-properties-c)

Does anyone know how to read information in a file's summary tab using C#?
Summary tab: Right click on file, then "Summary"

Thanks

Comment: Does not seem duplicate. The thread you mentioned is specific to media files whereas OP seems to be asking about any general file.

Comment: For which kind of file? (Btw Vijay, there is no Summary tab for 'any general file')

Comment: when I said 'any general file' I meant any file - txt/bmp/wav/doc/xls/any type you can think of. And on my machine 'Summary' tab is shown for all the files even their type is not registered.

Comment: @art (the OP): the 'Summary' you see in explorer gets data from the files in one of the following methods: 1 - File Streams: NTFS feature. 2-> some COM magic (e.g. MS Office files) where explorer uses some COM server to provide that data by reading information from the file itself (e.g Title, Author etc are stored within files created by MS Word).