# How do I read and write details from a file in C#

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Read/Write 'Extended' file properties (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220097/read-write-extended-file-properties-c)

I'm doing a list of files from a folder on a webpage and getting the files using DirectoryInfo and then using FileInfo. FileInfo has pretty much all info I need, but I'm missing one thing. It's the Author from the details "tab". I need to read and write the author so I can present that on the webpage. It doesn't really have to be the author in the details, just adding metadata or what not...

Anyone that can assist me with this issue?

Comment: Not every file has an Author...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/220097/read-write-extended-file-properties-c

Comment: ofc not, but I want to add one if so. That's why I need to both read and write the author.

Comment: @penartur I would prefer not to rely on a .dll. There HAS to be a way to do this without having to do so. Or maybe not?

Comment: To be clear, are you looking to extract metadata from the file system (ie. data external to the file), or from the file itself (within the file)?  Or both? :)

Comment: any of those would help :) as long as I can "save" the author information somewhere, without having to create my own db to store this info, linked to a document. So basically, as long as I can save the info somewhere, I'm glad :)