# Read a comment of the file

Tags: c#, extended-properties

Some files has Summary tab  in their Properties, This tab include information like Title, Author, Comments. Is there any way in C# to read the Comments of the file. I have to read only comments from image files like jpg.

Comment: look here [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/220097/read-write-extended-file-properties-c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/220097/read-write-extended-file-properties-c)

Answer (score 6):

The comments and other answer are good places to search. Here is some complete code to help you out. Ensure you reference `shell32.dll` first and the namespace `Shell32`. I've done this in LINQPad so it's a touch different.

Pick a test file and folder:

```
var folder = "...";
var file = "...";
```

Get the Shell objects:

```
// For our LINQPad Users
// var shellType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Shell.Application");
// dynamic app = Activator.CreateInstance(shellType);   

Shell32.Shell app = new Shell32.Shell();
```

Get the folder and file objects:

```
var folderObj = app.NameSpace(folder);
var filesObj = folderObj.Items();
```

Find the possible headers:

```
var headers = new Dictionary<string, int>();
for( int i = 0; i < short.MaxValue; i++ )
{
    string header = folderObj.GetDetailsOf(null, i);
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(header))
        break;
    if (!headers.ContainsKey(header)) headers.Add(header, i);
}
```

You can print these out if you like - that's all possible headers available in that directory. Let's use the header 'Comments' as an example:

```
var testFile = filesObj.Item(file);
Console.WriteLine("{0} -> {1}", testFile.Name, folderObj.GetDetailsOf(testFile, headers["Comments"]));
```

Modify as needed!

Comment: Almost equal to my beloved VBA background!!!!  `Set sh = CreateObject("shell.application")`

Answer (score 1):

The shell (shell32.dll) will help you to solve this poroblem. I recently found this great article on the MSDN (http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/94430444-283b-4a0e-9ca5-7375c8420622).

There is also a [codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5036/ID3-Tag-Reader-Using-Shell-Functions) on reading ID3 tags.