# regasm DLL Locations

Tags: dll, location, regasm

I'm constructing new classes in Visual Studio. These ultimately produce DLL files which are automatically registered via the VS IDE.

These same DLLs (and only the DLLs no TLBs) are shipped to the client where they are registered via the REGASM tool.

How can I identify which DLLs the client has registered, what versions these DLLs are and where these DLLs reside on a client machine?

I presume all of this is held within the registry, I just don't know where.

Thanks,
Keith

Comment: The only possible way your user has an existing DLL registered that uses the same Guid is when she got that DLL from you.  Apply normal COM techniques to avoid DLL Hell, change guids when you change interfaces.

Answer (score 2):

I think that the following page might give you a hint: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tzat5yw6(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tzat5yw6%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

All registered COM class
objects are listed under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID. If you register your COM+ in Component Services through an MSI, then search under Program Files\ComPlus Applications and you will find your dlls there.

Regarding the file properties please refer to [Read/Write 'Extended' file properties (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220097/read-write-extended-file-properties-c)