# How to set file version comment

Tags: c#, .net

Where can I set the file version comments..?

We can get it by

```
FileVersionInfo fv = 
System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(
                   Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
var comment = fv.Comments;
```

Then how can I set it so that I can show the same somewhere..

Comment: Where / How would you like to show them?

Comment: @KonstantinVasilcov in an about window of the application

Comment: What prevents you from doing `MessageBox.Show(comment,"About");`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/220097/read-write-extended-file-properties-c

Comment: Do you want to set it compile time when creating an assembly or do you need to manipulate existing assemblies?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For .NET Assemblies you can set the File Version Comments using the [AssemblyDescriptionAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblydescriptionattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which you usually put in the AssemblyInfo.cs file in your project when using Visual Studio.

```
[assembly: AssemblyDescription("The assembly does xxx by yyy")]
```

For other types of executables the file version is set using a resource in the file.

The different assembly level File Version attributes maps as follows:

- FileVersionInfo.Comments = AssemblyDescription
- FileVersionInfo.CompanyName = AssemblyCompany
- FileVersionInfo.FileDescription = AssemblyTitle
- FileVersionInfo.FileVersion = AssemblyFileVersion
- FileVersionInfo.LegalCopyright = AssemblyCopyright
- FileVersionInfo.LegalTrademarks = AssemblyTrademark
- FileVersionInfo.ProductName = AssemblyProduct
- FileVersionInfo.ProductVersion = AssemblyInformationalVersion

Comment: You're welcome. Feel free to accept the answer you think is most helpful, by marking it as "accepted".

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays in .Net 6

you can set comments in`*.csproj`

```
<Description>My Comment</Description>
```

And get

```
public static string GetComments()
{
    var fileName = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()?.Location;
    if (fileName == null) return String.Empty;
    var versionInfo = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(fileName);
    return versionInfo?.Comments ?? String.Empty; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To set this value, you can edit the `AssemblyInfo.cs` file of your project.

This line is what you are looking for:

```
[assembly: AssemblyDescription("This is the comment")]
```