# Get extended properties of a file on a network share

Tags: c#, windows, file-io, interop

I'm trying to read extended properties from music files on a network share (Author, Album, etc.)

This line (adapted from code at [Read/Write 'Extended' file properties (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220097/read-write-extended-file-properties-c))

```
objFolder = shell.Namespace(@"C:\somefolder");
```

Works but these lines set objFolder to null:

```
objFolder = shell.Namespace(@"\\nasdrive\somefolder");
```

(with Z mapped to \nasdrive)

```
objFolder = shell.Namespace(@"Z:\somefolder");
```

I have tried to use impersonation from http://platinumdogs.me/2008/10/30/net-c-impersonation-with-network-credentials/ to wrap the code but it's not working.

(The impersonation works for normal file access though: File.Open(...), etc)

How can I read these extended properties without moving the files to a local drive?

Answer (score 0):

If you're reading from a network share, why are you escaping special characters, then using 4 backslashes?

```
objFolder = shell.Namespace(@"\\\\nasdrive\somefolder");
```

I would think it should be:

```
objFolder = shell.Namespace(@"\\nasdrive\somefolder");
```

or

```
objFolder = shell.Namespace("\\\\nasdrive\\somefolder");
```