# How to get Image tag using C# application

Tags: c#, image

This is my image.
The image had tags = Jejemon; heller;

I want to get this tag using c# in application form.

[image]

This is my code:

```
 OpenFileDialog data = new OpenFileDialog();
 Image img = Image.FromFile(data.FileName);
```

when I look the img.tag shows null, but in my image had Jejemon; heller; tags.
How can I get the `img.Tag`?

---

This is the best answered I found.
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/08d4f986-b416-4a94-ae0c-13361c9929d1/extract-file-properties

Comment: You need to access the extended file properties - see my answer for a link to another SO question that might provide a solution.

Comment: The accept answer doesn't really solve the problem. I find the answer here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26646068/getting-metadata-information-from-a-file-using-c-sharp). And for a list of columns from GetDetailsOf, here is a useful overflow site: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22382010/what-options-are-available-for-shell32-folder-getdetailsof/37061433#37061433)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you might be talking about the EXIF metadata inside the image, if set. Take a look at this example: http://www.holmessoft.co.uk/homepage/Software/ExifUsage.htm

UPDATE: Could you perhaps provide a link to the original image file, so we can take a look at it in detail?

Answer (score 3):

What would you expect `img.Tag` to be? The `Tag` property is a property that can take any value you want, but it is not initialized by default to anything.

---

The `Tag` field does *not* contain the EXIF information or other image meta data - this is a misunderstanding on your end :-)

---

The information you're showing in your screen shot is not imported when you load an image. The `Tag` property in your code is in no way related to the file properties. You need to access the file properties. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220097/read-write-extended-file-properties-c) seems to provide an answer. One of the answers contains this:

> The solution to this is the property indexer FolderItem.ExtendedProperty and if you drop all spaces in the property's name, you'll get the value. E.g. File Version goes FileVersion, and there you have it.

Comment: To get the value Jejemon; heller; from tags

Comment: And why would you expect that?

Comment: @SeanPogz see edit. You need to get EXIF information or other file meta data from a different source.

Comment: @SeanPogz See my edit - you need to access the extended file properties.