# PowerShell get deleted files of a folder

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0, recycle-bin

I try get the deleted files of a folder using Get-ChildItem and Trash but its not working so well. In trash I can get the file, but i dont know how discover what file is of the folder that I executed the script.

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File #Can`t get deleted files

#I get the deleted files, but I dont know what folder they come
$Shell = New-Object -ComObject "Shell.Application"
($Shell.NameSpace(0xa)).items()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [`NameSpace` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/desktop/shell/shell-namespace) returns a [`Folder` object](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/desktop/shell/folder) which provides a [`GetDetailsOf` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/desktop/shell/folder-getdetailsof) you can use to retrieve details about each [member](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/desktop/shell/folderitem) of [`Items`](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/desktop/shell/folder-items):

```
New-Variable -Name 'ssfBITBUCKET'                       -Option Constant -Value 0x0A;
New-Variable -Name 'BitBucketDetails_Name'              -Option Constant -Value 0;
New-Variable -Name 'BitBucketDetails_ParentPath'        -Option Constant -Value 1;
New-Variable -Name 'BitBucketDetails_DeletionTimeText'  -Option Constant -Value 2;
New-Variable -Name 'BitBucketDetails_SizeText'          -Option Constant -Value 3;
New-Variable -Name 'BitBucketDetails_Type'              -Option Constant -Value 4;
New-Variable -Name 'BitBucketDetails_LastWriteTimeText' -Option Constant -Value 5;
New-Variable -Name 'BitBucketDetails_CreationTimeText'  -Option Constant -Value 6;
New-Variable -Name 'BitBucketDetails_LastAccessTimeText'-Option Constant -Value 7;
New-Variable -Name 'BitBucketDetails_AttributesText'    -Option Constant -Value 8;

$application = New-Object -ComObject 'Shell.Application';
$bitBucket = $application.NameSpace($ssfBITBUCKET);

foreach ($deletedItem in $bitBucket.Items())
{
    New-Object -TypeName 'PSObject' -Property @{
        # Same as $deletedItem.Name
        Name =               $bitBucket.GetDetailsOf($deletedItem, $BitBucketDetails_Name);
        ParentPath =         $bitBucket.GetDetailsOf($deletedItem, $BitBucketDetails_ParentPath);
        DeletionTimeText =   $bitBucket.GetDetailsOf($deletedItem, $BitBucketDetails_DeletionTimeText);
        Size =               $deletedItem.Size;
        SizeText =           $bitBucket.GetDetailsOf($deletedItem, $BitBucketDetails_SizeText);
        # Same as $deletedItem.Type
        Type =               $bitBucket.GetDetailsOf($deletedItem, $BitBucketDetails_Type);
        LastWriteTime =      $deletedItem.ModifyDate;
        LastWriteTimeText =  $bitBucket.GetDetailsOf($deletedItem, $BitBucketDetails_LastWriteTimeText);
        CreationTimeText =   $bitBucket.GetDetailsOf($deletedItem, $BitBucketDetails_CreationTimeText);
        LastAccessTimeText = $bitBucket.GetDetailsOf($deletedItem, $BitBucketDetails_LastAccessTimeText);
        AttributesText =     $bitBucket.GetDetailsOf($deletedItem, $BitBucketDetails_AttributesText);
        IsFolder =           $deletedItem.IsFolder();
        BitBucketPath =      $deletedItem.Path;
    };
}
```

`ssfBITBUCKET` is from the [`ShellSpecialFolderConstants` enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/desktop/api/shldisp/ne-shldisp-shellspecialfolderconstants).  On my Windows 10 system set to the `en-US` culture, when a `BitBucketDetails_*TimeText` constant is passed to `GetDetailsOf()` it returns not a `DateTime` instance but a timestamp in the form of a `String` where the year, month, and day are each preceded by a [left-to-right mark (`[Char] 0x200E`)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left-to-right_mark) and the time is preceded by a [right-to-left mark (`[Char] 0x200F`)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-to-left_mark) followed by a left-to-right mark.

I determined the `BitBucketDetails_*` constants myself since I didn't find them documented anywhere, but according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37061433/150605) you can query for them by passing `$null` as the first parameter to `GetDetailsOf()`.  Thus, you can keep querying the column names from the bit bucket namespace until it starts returning empty `String`s like this...

```
New-Variable -Name 'ssfBITBUCKET' -Option Constant -Value 0x0A;

$application = New-Object -ComObject 'Shell.Application';
$bitBucket = $application.NameSpace($ssfBITBUCKET);

for ($column = 0; -not [String]::IsNullOrEmpty(($details = $bitbucket.GetDetailsOf($null, $column))); $column++)
{
    New-Object -TypeName 'PSObject' -Property @{
        Column = $column;
        Name = $details;
    };
}
```

...which outputs this on my system...

```
Column Name
------ ----
     0 Name
     1 Original Location
     2 Date Deleted
     3 Size
     4 Item type
     5 Date modified
     6 Date created
     7 Date accessed
     8 Attributes
     ...
```