# Do the Shell32 Atttributes from GetDetailsOf() change across Folders?

Tags: c#, dll

I am using Shell32 in a C# app to get extended properties from files in multiple directories (specifically from pictures across many folders).  A technique I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/2096315/edit) on SO (that works great)  for doing this is:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<string> arrHeaders = new List<string>();

    Shell32.Shell shell = new Shell32.Shell();
    Shell32.Folder objFolder;

    objFolder = shell.NameSpace(@"C:\temp\testprop");

    for( int i = 0; i < short.MaxValue; i++ )
    {
        string header = objFolder.GetDetailsOf(null, i);
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(header))
            break;
        arrHeaders.Add(header);
    }

    foreach(Shell32.FolderItem2 item in objFolder.Items())
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < arrHeaders.Count; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(
              $"{i}\t{arrHeaders[i]}: {objFolder.GetDetailsOf(item, i)}");
        }
    }
}
```

I did a little investigation and it looks like the attribute names (not their values, obviously) are the same across all of the folders on my C: drive.  Does anyone know if I can count on this?  (I'm using Windows 10.)  There doesn't seem to be a lot of good Microsoft documentation that I could find .

[Edit] I wrote a quick program to scan all of the directories I could and then count how many of them had which attributes.  Here is the result; I'm not sure what it tells me, other than most, but not all, of the attributes are common across most (but not all) folders:

```
Attribute                 Directories
------------------------- -----------
#                         203485
Album                     203485
Attributes                203485
Authors                   203485
Availability              203485
Bit rate                  203485
Camera maker              203485
Camera model              203485
Categories                203485
Category                  1
Collection                1
Comments                  203485
Company                   203485
Conductors                203485
Contributing artists      203485
Copyright                 203485
Creation Date             1
Date accessed             203485
Date created              203486
Date Deleted              1
Date modified             203488
Date taken                203485
Designed for              1
Designer/foundry          1
Dimensions                203485
Family                    1
File description          203485
Folder path               2
Font embeddability        1
Font file names           1
Font style                1
Font type                 1
Font version              1
Genre                     203485
Item type                 203487
Kind                      203485
Last Accessed             1
Last Synchronization      1
Length                    203485
Location                  1
Masters keywords          406974
Name                      203489
Offline status            203485
Original Location         1
Owner                     203485
Perceived type            203485
Program File              1
Protected                 203485
Rating                    203485
Show/hide                 1
Size                      203489
Status                    2
Subject                   203485
Tags                      203487
Time Period               1
Title                     203485
Total Size                1
Version                   1
Year                      203485
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What options are available for Shell32.Folder.GetDetailsOf(..,..)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22382010/what-options-are-available-for-shell32-folder-getdetailsof)

Comment: It appears that the attributes can vary across file systems, which means differ on different drives, but not folders with-in a filesystem/drive.

Comment: Nope.  You are seeing the side-effects of [meta-data handler extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/handlers) installed on your machine.  Anything is possible.

Comment: @Hans.  That looks like it.  Thanks.  If you'd like to add a few more points to get you closer to the Magic Million Mark, I'd be happy to mark it as an answer.  (If not, I'll probably answer my own question.)