# Is there a way to delete all images in a folder which are less than a certain width via Windows Batch?

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, command-line

I'd like to write a simple program to extract the windows spotlight images from the system directory where they live to a folder where I can more easily get at them. So far I have this:

```
@ECHO OFF
if not exist "%homedrive%%homepath%\Downloads\Spotlight" mkdir %homedrive%%homepath%\Downloads\Spotlight
xcopy /s %homedrive%%homepath%\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.Windows.ContentDeliveryManager_cw5n1h2txyewy\LocalState\Assets\ %homedrive%%homepath%\Downloads\Spotlight
ren %homedrive%%homepath%\Downloads\Spotlight\* *.jpg
```

Which successfully copies the contents of the spotlight directory into a new folder, then renames all the files to make them JPGs. However, a number of miscellaneous icons come too, as well as the 'portrait mode' spotlight images. I'd like to delete them by checking each .jpg in the output folder to see if its width is less than 1920 pixels, and deleting the image if so.

I went to AI to try and solve my problem, but failed:

```
set "SpotlightFolder=%USERPROFILE%\Downloads\Spotlight"
:: Iterate over all .jpg files and delete those with width smaller than 1920 pixels
for %%F in ("%SpotlightFolder%\*.jpg") do (
    for /f %%W in ('powershell -command "& {(Get-ImageDimensions '%%~F').Width}"') do set "Width=%%W"
    if !Width! lss 1920 (
        echo Deleting: %%~nxF
        del "%%F"
    ) else (
        echo Keeping: %%~nxF
    )
)

:: PowerShell script to get image dimensions
<#
function Get-ImageDimensions {
    param([string]$filePath)
    $image = [System.Drawing.Image]::FromFile($filePath)
    $width = $image.Width
    $image.Dispose()
    $width
}
#>
```

This returns a nebulous 'The syntax of the command is incorrect' error, and deletes all the images in the folder, regardless of dimension.
Any help would be appreciated.

The solution is marked below, but for anyone with the same question, this is the complete script I've created to solve my problem; since the answer ended up being in Powershell script I rewrote the beginning of my code in that language.

```
$minWidth = 1900
$SpotlightFolder = "${env:USERPROFILE}\Downloads\Spotlight"


If(!(test-path -PathType container $SpotlightFolder))
{
      New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $SpotlightFolder
}

xcopy /s "$env:USERPROFILE\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.Windows.ContentDeliveryManager_cw5n1h2txyewy\LocalState\Assets\" $SpotlightFolder

#Get-ChildItem -Path $SpotlightFolder | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace '$.*', '.jpg' }
#Rename all items to make them JPGs, accounting for the possibility that they already exist (avoid 'cannot overwrite via rename' error)
Get-ChildItem -Path $SpotlightFolder | ForEach-Object {
    $newName = $_.BaseName + ".jpg"
    $newPath = Join-Path -Path $_.DirectoryName -ChildPath $newName

    if (-not (Test-Path $newPath)) {
        Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName $newName
    }
}
#Delete all items which do not have an extension (those which already existed and didn't get renamed)
Get-ChildItem -Path $SpotlightFolder | Where-Object { -not $_.Extension } | Remove-Item -Force


$widthColumnNum = 176 # or 165 or some other value, see below for details
$shell = New-Object -COMObject Shell.Application
$shellfolder = $shell.Namespace($SpotlightFolder)


#Uncomment the Write-Output code and run to see Windows' list of attributes. Find the number corresponding to 'Width'. Replace '176' if it is different for you.
$objFolder = (New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application).Namespace('c:\')
for ($columnNumber = 0; $columnNumber -lt 500; ++$columnNumber) 
{ 
    $columnName = $objFolder.GetDetailsOf($objFolder.Items, $columnNumber) 
    if ($columnName)
    {
        #Write-Output "$(([string]$columnNumber).PadLeft(3)) $columnName"
    }
}

Get-ChildItem -Filter *.jpg $SpotlightFolder | Where-Object {
    $shellfile = $shellfolder.ParseName($_.Name)
    $w = $shellfolder.GetDetailsOf($shellfile, $widthColumnNum)
    [int]([regex]::Match($w, "\d+").Value) -lt $minWidth
} | Remove-Item #-WhatIf
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What lets you think, Poweshell has access to a part of the batch script?

Comment: BTW, your first code submission could probably be reduced to just **1.** ```@%SystemRoot%\System32\xcopy.exe "%LocalAppData%\Packages\Microsoft.Windows.ContentDeliveryManager_cw5n1h2txyewy\LocalState\Assets" "%UserProfile%\Downloads\Spotlight\"```, and **2.** ```@Ren "%UserProfile%\Downloads\Spotlight\*" *.jpg```. XCopy will create the destination, if it does not already exist, and you have a trailing backward slash on that destination. _(it's one of the only times you should need to use a trailing backward slash for a directory)_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `System.Drawing.Image` might not be very efficient because it actually decodes and loads the whole image. The metadata can be accessed directly using [Shell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/scriptable-shell-objects-roadmap) [COM object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/shell)'s [`Folder.GetDetailsOf()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/folder-getdetailsof) so it's very cheap to get the images' widths. Here's a simple PowerShell script to do what you want:

```
$minWidth = 1920
$SpotlightFolder = "${env:USERPROFILE}\Downloads\Spotlight"

$widthColumnNum = 176 # or 165 or some other value, see below for details
$shell = New-Object -COMObject Shell.Application
$shellfolder = $shell.Namespace($SpotlightFolder)

Get-ChildItem -Filter *.jpg $SpotlightFolder | Where-Object {
    $shellfile = $shellfolder.ParseName($_.Name)
    $w = $shellfolder.GetDetailsOf($shellfile, $widthColumnNum)
    [int]([regex]::Match($w, "\d+").Value) -lt $minWidth
} | Remove-Item -WhatIf
```

Basically this lists all *.jpg files in the specified path, filter the ones with `Width` less than `$minWidth` to pass to `Remove-Item`. Remove the `-WhatIf` option to do actual removing

The column number 165 is magic which is taken from [here](https://dot-sharp.com/en/net-getdetailsof-en/), or 176 based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22382010/995714). You can run the PowerShell script in [What options are available for Shell32.Folder.GetDetailsOf(..,..)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22382010/995714) to find the actual value on your system in case it's different:

```
$objFolder = (New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application).Namespace('c:\')
for ($columnNumber = 0; $columnNumber -lt 500; ++$columnNumber) 
{ 
    $columnName = $objFolder.GetDetailsOf($objFolder.Items, $columnNumber) 
    if ($columnName)
    {
        Write-Output "$(([string]$columnNumber).PadLeft(3)) $columnName"
    }
}
```

I've already tested it on my PC and it works, the image width is field 176 as expected. Of course you can also automate the method to get that magic number but I'm keeping it simple here

For more information about metadata reading check

- [Use PowerShell to Find Metadata from Photograph Files](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/use-powershell-to-find-metadata-from-photograph-files/)
- [Get MP3/MP4 File’s MetaData](https://geekeefy.wordpress.com/2016/10/15/powershell-get-mp3mp4-files-metadata-and-how-to-use-it-to-make-you-life-easy/)

Because it uses COM objects, it can be called from any languages that support COM objects, for example a JS, VBS or [hybrid VBS/hybrid JS](https://superuser.com/a/1512193/241386)

Comment: This results in the error:
Cannot convert value "74d5cee167e1e31f11aa84294db43c2b06815f160af6325907c04f13fda1a379.jpg" to type "System.Int32".
Error: "Input string was not in a correct format."
At C:\Users\\Downloads\remove.ps1:10 char:5
+     [int]($shellfolder.GetDetailsOf($shellfile, $widthColumnNum)) -lt ...
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidCastFromStringToInteger
I see similar results online but nothing mentions JPGs.

Comment: @AL2044 I've already fixed the script and it works fine on my PC. Make sure the column number and the path is correct

Answer (score 1):

Here is a .bat file script that will remove .jpeg files with a width less than 1000.
Edit the PICDIR and MIN_WIDTH values to your liking. When you are satisfied that the correct files will be removed, remove the `-WhatIf` from the `Remove-Item` command.

```bash
SET "PICDIR=%USERPROFILE%\Pictures"
SET "MIN_WIDTH=1000"
pwsh -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command ^
    "Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing;" ^
    "$PicDir = '"%PICDIR%"';" ^
    "Get-ChildItem -File -Path $PicDir -Filter '*.jpeg' |" ^
        "ForEach-Object {" ^
            "$Image = [System.Drawing.Image]::FromFile($_.FullName);" ^
            "if ($Image.Width -lt %MIN_WIDTH%) { $_ };" ^
            "$Image.Dispose();" ^
        "} |" ^
        "Remove-Item -WhatIf;"
```

Comment: I've tried this option, I needed to swap 'pwsh' for 'powershell'...
Apart from that, when I run the .bat file I the command just prints out and does nothing. I'm baffled; it displays no error but does not delete anything.
powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command     "$PicDir = '"C:\Users\~\Downloads\Spotlight"';"     "Get-ChildItem -File -Path $PicDir -Filter '*.jpeg' |"         "ForEach-Object {"             "$Image = [System.Drawing.Image]::FromFile($_.FullName);"             "if ($Image.Width -lt 1900) { $_ };"             "$Image.Dispose();"         "} |"         "Remove-Item;"

Comment: Oh, you are on the older Windows PowerShell and not PowerShell Core. What happens if you also remove the `-File` switch from `Get-ChildItem`?

Comment: @lit `-File` exists in PowerShell so it should work

Comment: I get System.Drawing.Image is not found...

Comment: Try adding the `Add-Type` statement. I might be required for Windows PowerShell, but not for the current PowerShell Core. https://github.com/powershell/powershell