# Get length and bitrate from audio file in Windows Azure

Tags: c#, audio, azure, bitrate, azure-media-services

I need to get audio file metadata such as bitrate from files uploaded to an Azure web site. Based on this information I want to decide how to transcode the file using Azure Media Services.

I've used Shell32.dll to read properties of audio files earlier. See this post for how: [Read/Write 'Extended' file properties (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220097/read-write-extended-file-properties-c)

However when I bring the same code to Azure, I don't get any properties back. As far as I know there is no way to get this from WAMS.

How can I get the bitrate from an audio file uploaded to a website or WAMS?

Comment: What kind of audio file(s)?

Comment: Could be both aac/mp4 and mp3.