# Getting extended file properties

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

[I found this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220097/read-write-extended-file-properties-c/2096315#2096315).

That explains how to get extended file properties in .net.  But it points to a Code Project article that is 10 years old.

The thread itself is 5 years old.

Is there a better way now to get extended file properties like Title, SubTitle, Episode Name etc.?

What I would really like to do is to get the extended file information on individual files.  It looks to me like this code loops through a directory and gets the file info on those files.

Comment: Does the code in that thread work or not?

Comment: Is this a duplicate of [Read/Write 'Extended' file properties \(C\#\)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220097/read-write-extended-file-properties-c)?

Answer (score 1):

I used already the **Windows API Code Pack**

```
ShellObject picture = ShellObject.FromParsingName(file);

var camera = picture.Properties.GetProperty(SystemProperties.System.Photo.CameraModel);
newItem.CameraModel = GetValue(camera, String.Empty, String.Empty);

var company = picture.Properties.GetProperty(SystemProperties.System.Photo.CameraManufacturer);
newItem.CameraMaker = GetValue(company, String.Empty, String.Empty);
```

Link to a Blogpost by *Rob Sanders* - [Link removed. It was pointing to malware.]

Comment: There is also a NuGet-Package [WindowsAPICodePack-Core](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAPICodePack-Core)

Comment: The link to the blogpost now redirects randomly to suspicious pages full of deceiving downloading links...

Answer (score 0):

You can use my [MetadataExtractor](https://github.com/drewnoakes/metadata-extractor-dotnet) library to access all sorts of metadata from image and video files. It supports Exif, IPTC, and many other kinds of metadata.

It's available on [GitHub](https://github.com/drewnoakes/metadata-extractor-dotnet) and [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MetadataExtractor).

Answer (score 0):

In order to get this code to run you will need to add two nugget packages - I had to add older version from the package manager console as the latest version wouldn't install on my antediluvian VS 2012:

```
    Install-Package WindowsAPICodePack-Core -Version 1.1.2
    Install-Package WindowsAPICodePack-Shell -Version 1.1.1
```

Below is some code to list all the properties:

```
 using Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Shell;

    private void ListExtendedProperties(string filePath)
    {
        var file = ShellObject.FromParsingName(filePath);
        var i = 0;
        foreach (var property in file.Properties.DefaultPropertyCollection)
        {
            var name = (property.CanonicalName ?? "unnamed-[" + i + "]").Replace("System.", string.Empty);
            var t = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(property.ValueType) ?? property.ValueType;
            var value = (null == property.ValueAsObject)
                ? string.Empty
                : (Convert.ChangeType(property.ValueAsObject, t)).ToString();
            var friendlyName = property.Description.DisplayName;
            Console.WriteLine(i++ + " " + name + "/" + friendlyName + ": " + value);
        }
    }
```