# How to get all file properties of an Image in C# winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, media

I am trying to get all properties in C# of an Image file downloaded from camera. I can get general file properties using `FileInfo` and `FileAttributes`. But image taken from camera have special properties tab named Camera what I want to retrieve in C#. Here is the snapshot of properties.
[image: example image]

I want to get special properties like ISO, f-Stops and camera name in C#. Is there any class which can be used to get that or any other open source project?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/220097/read-write-extended-file-properties-c

Comment: The Image class does this just fine, use its GetPropertyItem() method.  The dreary task of mapping a number to a string and displaying it in a Form is however your job to take care of if you don't just want to use the built-in Windows property sheet.  It is the kind of project that has been started many times but never finished :)

Comment: thank you!!! to fixation, that code gives everything! including what i want.. managed to filter out my required field :) thank you v much to u and to the guy who posted solution to that thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can find more info about this
http://www.developerfusion.com/article/84474/reading-writing-and-photo-metadata/

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of examples online, i.e:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xddt0dz7(v=vs.110).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-Us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.fileproperties.imageproperties?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1

http://tech.pro/tutorial/782/getting-image-metadata-with-csharp