# Listview - add File type & Last modified Subitems

Tags: vb.net, listview

I'm trying to add "file type" and "last modified" to my Listview when adding items in It same as in Explorer, but I don't find what property should be assigned to SubItem. Here is my code:

```
For Each MyFile As IO.FileInfo In ItemDirectory.GetFiles

    Dim lvi As New ListViewItem

    lvi.Tag = mFile.FullName
    lvi.Text = mFile.Name
    lvi.ImageKey = CacheShellIcon(mFile.FullName)

    Listview1.Items.Add(lvi)
    lvi.SubItems.Add("File type ??")
    lvi.SubItems.Add(mFile.LastAccessTime.ToShortDateString & " " & mFile.LastAccessTime.ToShortTimeString) 'This isn't same as last modified ? 
 Next
```

If somebody knows how to do It please let me know, I want to have this in my Details view.

Comment: The file type isnt part of the file system.  it is determined by the registry entry for the app which has that extension registered.  I think you can get it from Shell32 as one of the "extended properties"

Comment: @plutonix, you have any link for that ? I searched a lot but haven't found anything.

Comment: [This will get you started](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26144984/1070452) read the follow on comments: there are now 300+ entries (not 34), the one you want is 9, I believe.  The 34 comes from the original ones in Win95(?) and are real well known.  Note also that after index 290 or so they move around from their after in W7

Comment: @Plutonix thanks, I'll dig into this, I hope I'll manage It.

Comment: ^^ `they move around from their index after W7`  I updated the post with a version that should harvest all the elements that it can  up to 310

Comment: @Plutonix I tried both suggestions but my code doesn't produce anything. I must be doing something wrong. I added reference "Microsoft Shell Controls and Automation" ("Microsoft Shell Folder View Router" is not available in my COM) and tried to add "s.Name" in Msgbox - as mentioned, nothing happened. I tried to do a console.Writeline too, but I don't know how to use console, It doesn't open for me.

Comment: **Debug Menu -> Windows -> Output** opens/adds a window to VS where Console.Write and DEBUG.Print output goes.  Open the immediate window too - depending on other settings it may go there.  I cant tell whats wrong with so little (no) details, but if it compiles and runs it should mean the references are all there.  COuld be how you use it or a typo in the implementation

Comment: @Plutonix, Thanks for console info, now I se It, I allways thought that another window as cmd should be opened. However this code still doesn't produce anything - I use code like this "***Dim xtd As List(Of ShellInfo) = GetXtdShellInfo("D:\VideosI\Zars.mp3")***". When I tried with .docx file, I got error: "***Object reference not set to an instance of the object***". Also, in you code - this line : "***If shfolder.GetDetailsOf(s, 0).ToLowerInvariant = Path.GetFileName(file).ToLowerInvariant Then***" - what does "file" represent, should It be "filepath" there ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26144984/1070452) provides an all-purpose way to get all the extended properties.  With 300+ elements in newer Windows versions it is clearly overkill to fetch them all if you are only interested in one or two.  This returns *just* the file type. A better approach might be to pass a "shopping list" of desired property names.

As before, you need to add a reference to **Microsoft Shell Controls and Automation** or **Microsoft Shell Folder View Router** based on your OS version.

```
Imports Shell32
Imports SHDocVw

Partial Friend Class Shell32Methods

    Friend Shared Function GetShellFileProperty(filepath As String, index As Int32) As String
        Dim shell As New Shell32.Shell
        Dim shFolder As Shell32.Folder
        shFolder = shell.NameSpace(Path.GetDirectoryName(filepath))

        ' get shell data for this file, cast to folder item
        Dim shFolderItem = DirectCast(shFolder.Items().Item(Path.GetFileName(filepath)), 
                            Shell32.ShellFolderItem)

        If shFolderItem IsNot Nothing Then
            Return shFolder.GetDetailsOf(shFolderItem, index)
        Else
            Return String.Empty
        End If
    End Function
        ...
End Class
```

Usage:

```
Dim lvi As ListViewItem
Dim fileType As String

For Each f As String In Directory.EnumerateFiles("C:\Temp\ShellTest")
    fileType = Shell32Methods.GetShellFileProperty(f, 9)

    lvi = New ListViewItem
    lvi.Text = Path.GetFileName(f)
    lvi.SubItems.Add(fileType)
    lvFiles.Items.Add(lvi)

Next
```

[image]

Ideally, you'd want to create an Enum for the properties so the code could avoid magic numbers:

```
fileType = Shell32Methods.GetShellFileProperty(f, Shell32FileProps.FileType)
```

As noted elsewhere, the index of the ones >260 or so can change depending on the OS version.  That could be easily modified to accept an Enum/Int array and return a list of values so as to prevent iterating all 300+ propertied to get one or three.

Answer (score 1):

For filetype you can use `lvi.SubItems.Add(MyFile.Extension)`
and for the "last modified" date, of course the last modified! :D
`lvi.SubItems.Add(MyFile.LastWriteTime.ToShortDateString)`

Last write and last access are not the same ;)

Comment: thanks for LastWriteTime, youre absolutely right, that's what happen when you must translate each thing first to yourself:) File extension is something simmilar yes, but I'll try Plutonix suggestion too.

Comment: You are welcome ;) dont forget to vote my answer if you find that solve your problem :)

Comment: @LuckyLuke82 the file extension (e.g. `jpg`) is not the same thing as the file type "as in Explorer" (text, image, video etc) unless there is no file associated the extension then it is "FOO file"

Comment: @Plutonix, yes I reailize that. I will try for extended properties, I want that on my Listview.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out another solution, I think this one is easier, at least for me :

```
 Public Function ExProperty(filepath As String, PropertyItem As Integer)
        Dim arrHeaders As New List(Of String)()

        Dim shell As New Shell
        Dim rFolder As Folder = shell.[NameSpace](Path.GetDirectoryName(filepath))
        Dim rFiles As FolderItem = rFolder.ParseName(Path.GetFileName(filepath))

        'I needed only File type so I looped to 2 only (2 is the file type in my case - Windows 10 - 
        ' to see all available properties do a loop 
        ' 0 To Short.MaxValue - 1" and then extract whatever property you like)
                    For i As Integer = 0 To 2
                        Dim value As String = rFolder.GetDetailsOf(rFiles, i).Trim()
                        arrHeaders.Add(value)
                    Next

        Dim DesiredProperty As String
        DesiredProperty = arrHeaders.Item(PropertyItem)

        Return DesiredProperty

 End Function
```

Usage with Listview just simply (this adds File type subitem):

```
Listview1_Item.SubItems.Add(ExProperty(filepath, 2))
```

As in all solutions, a reference to ***Microsoft Shell Controls and Automation*** must be set.

Comment: @Plutonix, this is my solution as I told. Do you think It's ok ?....Anyway, thanks for your guidance, your answers are just simply the best !!

Comment: Index 2 is the file association (e.g. "Video Lan video file"), #9 is the actual file type (Image, video, email etc)...there is an even shorter way than that though

Comment: @Plutonix, you're right, I'll fix this. Thanks again !!

Comment: Either can be the right one, it just depends on what you want. I like passing the index so it can be a generic property getter

Comment: updated the answer for the shorter version.  I think the `shFolder.Items().Item(...)` syntax is kind of creepy