# Getting MP4 property data in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, properties

I’d like to know if there’s any possible way i can get the file title or comments as a string in VB.NET. It’s easy to get the file name but the title under details in the actual files properties seems much harder to get. I need to get the entire property title of a MP4 file i give it. Thanks. I do not have much knowledge of VB but I’m hoping someone can help me :)

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
Dim information = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFileInfo("C:\myfile.mp4")
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo?view=netframework-4.8

To get more information, this could be a possible answer:
[Get extended file information details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26142723/get-extended-file-information-details)