# Windows Files - Tags or Keywords - How to access them (Read/Write)

Tags: windows, tags, keyword

I am trying to have an application I am building access tags or keywords a user might assign to a file through the file explorer UI. I have been searching for hours through the documentation and StackOverflow, but can't find anything to get me pointed in the right direction.

From the Windows, file explorer people are able to add and edit tags associated with a file. Yet from my code VB.NET or C# I can't find any way to access that information for the file.

Do you know how that might be done with VB.NET, C# or any other approaches?

Comment: Most likely what you are looking for is the [Windows Property System](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/properties/windows-properties-system)

Comment: I have been thinking that, and have been all over the Windows Properties and have not yet found where it is hiding. Fairly frustrated and welcome any good guidance on where to find it inside properties.

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26142723/get-extended-file-information-details)