# Read custom properties from file

Tags: c#, tablet-pc, custom-properties, customproperty

I am trying to **read the custom properties** from a **Solid Edge file** (*Right clic -> Properties -> Custom tab*).

But I found only 2 types of code.

The first is for read/set custom properties on a **Office document** (like .doc / .docx). And the second is from the Solid Edge API (http://www.plm.automation.siemens.com/zh_cn/Images/Solid_Edge_API_tcm78-125829.pdf) ~ page 150, where I can get the custom properties but it **needs to have Solid Edge on the device**.

My problem is : The C# program will be run on a Tablet and this tablets **don't have Solid Edge**. So I need another way to get the custom properties.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Check this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/220097/read-write-extended-file-properties-c

Comment: Yeah I can read a looot of properties, but not the properties I want to have. This is what I need to read : http://hpics.li/9497ebe

Comment: OK, so I had a quick look at the PDF. Can you not just add required DLLs to your set up project and use the standard API? Also, can you view these custom properties on tablets where Solid Edge is not installed?

Comment: I am able to see the properties of the file without install Solid Edge. And I already tryied with the DLLs but in the code I got an error at this line : "propertySets = new SolidEdgeFileProperties.PropertySets();". Error : 80040154 Not registered class (HRESULT : 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).
To see the whole method code : http://pastebin.com/xAbh99is