# Application freezes when trying to read Author from .doc multiple files

Tags: c#, winforms, .doc

I'm trying to make an app that displays all authors of .doc files from a Folder and its subfolders, the problem is that I used `Directory.GetFiles("*.doc", SearchOption.AllDirectories)` and when I'm trying to read from a folder with very much files, the app freeze in this point.
Here is my code

```
FileInfo[] Files = dir.GetFiles("*.doc", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
foreach(FileInfo file in Files) 
{
    try
    {
        //ConvertDOCToDOCX(file.FullName);
        using(WordprocessingDocument sourcePresentationDocument = WordprocessingDocument.Open(file.FullName, false)) 
        {
            metadataList.Add(new Metadata() 
            {
                Name = "Title", Value = file.Name
            });
            metadataList.Add(new Metadata() 
            {
                Name = "Author", Value = sourcePresentationDocument.PackageProperties.Creator
            });
            metadataList.Add(new Metadata() 
            {
                Name = "", Value = ""
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you dont need this "WordprocessingDocument" - this is producing a heavy load - you can just read the meta-information via .net default file methods.

For an example, you should take a look at [Read/Write 'Extended' file properties (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220097/read-write-extended-file-properties-c/2096315#2096315)

Comment: thanks,it helped but is there any way to check all subdirectories of the path with shell32?

Comment: I dont think so, you have to iterate through all folders recursively

Answer (score 0):

> the app freeze in this point

Yes, because you're doing a lot of work in the UI thread. Don't do that - never do that.

You should probably do all that work in a background thread (either with `BackgroundWorker` or maybe `Task.Run`) and then only modify the UI (on the UI thread) when you're done.