# How to get server name from file information?

Tags: c#

On the Details tab of the file properties in Windows, the last item under Owner is 'Computer'.  Does anyone know how to retrieve this information in C#?  I have a requirement to get the server name where a file was created.

Comment: No, an example would be if a server copies a file to a shared directory on another server.  How can you tell where the file originated from?

Comment: Apparently this will do it [Read/Write 'Extended' file properties (C#)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/220097/119477)