# How to get the file author using C#

Tags: c#

I'd like to know how to get the file author using C#, Not the file **owner** but the file **Author**, because when searching I find just how to get the file owner.

I already try this:

```
 string user = System.IO.File.GetAccessControl(file).GetOwner(typeof(System.Security.Principal.NTAccount)).ToString();
```

But this get the file owner.

Comment: And how would you define the file Author?

Comment: Maybe this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/220097/read-write-extended-file-properties-c/2096315#2096315?

Comment: Files don't have authors.

Comment: @SLaks - some have that property. have a look at the properties of a word file

Comment: Are you talking of things such as word/office documents? so in there there is a property of author I believe, or, any file, in which case you can only go by creator or last updated user.

Comment: @fubo Yes, but it's not part of the file system. You actually have to open the file, parse it and read the author. It's just one of the complicated things Explorer makes look easy :)

Comment: @MarkJansen when selecting a file, in the bottom there is some properties of the file (name, title, authors, lastmodified, .....)