# How to save extra information in MSG file?

Tags: c#, .net

I have some plugin for Outlook that among other things save email messages to HDD.

I save message like this:

```
mail.SaveAs("C:\temp\mail001.msg", Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlSaveAsType.olMSG);
```

Now when mail is stored to hdd some system windows properties are not saved, like From address, To address, Has attachments etc.

[image]

As you can see on image these columns in explorer are  empty.

I wonder is there any way to fill System.Message properties in msg file that is stored to hdd ?

Comment: I found solution for this on this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/220097/read-write-extended-file-properties-c

Comment: Basiclly you need to install Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Shell and Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Shell.PropertySystem NuGet packages and you can edit all System File properties.