# can't get the office files tags using c#

Tags: c#

I try to get the file property *tags* by using the C# shellfile class but I don't success.

How this really works?

Even if I have tag to the file, I can't get it.

```
var tags = (string[])shellFile.Properties.System.Keywords.ValueAsObject;
tags = tags ?? new string[0];

if (tags.Length != 0)
{
    foreach (string str in tags)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("keyword:" + str);
    }
}
```

This is the error that I get.

{"Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt."}

Comment: it looks good, what are you getting  printted?????

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read/Write 'Extended' file properties (C#)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/220097/read-write-extended-file-properties-c)

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks good, actually. This seems to be a permissions issue. Check to see what user context your app is running under. And make sure your file has proper permissions for that user. Here's a reference from way back:

http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?208213-The-file-is-not-a-valid-compound-file