# How to get missing "Frame height" and "Frame width" properties of a video file in C# using Shell32 (Windows 10)?

Tags: c#, windows, windows-10, shell32, extended-properties

I'm trying to determine the resolution of video files using Shell32 in C#, but the properties return empty strings, although Windows shell displays the information just fine.

Please note that I cannot incorporate any 3rd party libraries for this task (DirectShow or others).

This behavior persists for different video files. Sadly, none of the answers provided in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220097/read-write-extended-file-properties-c) have been helpful.

I am using the following code to extract the information:

```cs
Shell32.Shell shell = new Shell32.Shell();
Shell32.Folder objFolder;

objFolder = shell.NameSpace(Path.GetDirectoryName(videoFile.FullName));
FolderItem objFile = objFolder.ParseName(videoFile.Name);

List<string> arrHeaders = new List<string>();
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
  string header = objFolder.GetDetailsOf(null, i);
  if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(header))
    continue;
  arrHeaders.Add(header);
}

var length = objFolder.GetDetailsOf(
  objFile, arrHeaders.FindIndex(h => h == "Length"));
var resWidth = objFolder.GetDetailsOf(
  objFile, arrHeaders.FindIndex(h => h == "Frame width"));
var resHeight = objFolder.GetDetailsOf(
  objFile, arrHeaders.FindIndex(h => h == "Frame height"));
```

For the following file, I expect `resWidth` to have the value `"1920"` and `resHeight` to have the value `"1080"` but they both hold empty strings. Both properties exist in `arrHeaders`, specifically in indexes 301 and 303 on my system.

[image: Hearthstone.mp4 file properties]

As a side note, the `Length` property works as expected.

Comment: Are you sure [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3547482/70345) does not help?

Answer (score 0):

Wow, sorry about that. I seem to have totally skipped over the fact that I enumerate the indexes incorrectly since I skip empty headers.  Problem solved!