# How to list the metadata of multiple files

Tags: powershell, metadata

I would like to be able to interrogate a storage device to generate a list of the files it contains and various bits of metadata about the files. They are primarily video and image files, so information such as dimensions, dpi and duration would be useful. We use md5 hashes for checking file fixity, so excluding .md5 files would be beneficial.

I have used the following PowerShell script which yields great results for basic file metadata, but I haven't been able to figure out how to add the additional metadata I require:

`gci -path "E:\\Files” -file -recurse | select-object fullname, name, length, lastwritetime, CreationTime, Extension | export-csv c:\\temp\\Files_Contents.txt`

Is there a simple way to find this additional metadata?

Comment: Ditto what @mklement0 said. You have to access the files to extract EXIF metadata. Can you run through them once to extract the data and build a dictionary/database that would help you?

Comment: Hi Both, many thanks for your answers - I realised that actually, mentioning LTO is a bit of a red herring - I will edit that out of my original question. The storage devices holds it's own metadata about the content - we are able to right click and view properties of files without the file needing to be read from the tape.

It might be possible to interrogate this metadata that the device holds, but I was hoping that there might be a simple addition to the script I posted to find the additional properties of the files.

Comment: At least with normal files, you can use the `Shell.Application` COM object, as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64601307/45375), for instance.