# Read 'Extended' file properties (C++)

Tags: c++, windows, file, properties

Is there a way to get all the properties and values of any file under the details tab using only c++ Code?
All extended file properties: [link](http://www.mendipdatasystems.co.uk/extended-file-properties/4594398115)
I have seen solutions for c# but not c++. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220097/read-write-extended-file-properties-c)
[image: File properties of a png file]

I have already looked into the `fileapi.h` function `GetFileAttributesA()` which gave me access to the file attribute constants like `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_COMPRESSED, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_READONLY...`

Even the `GetFileAttributesExA()` with `GetFileExMaxInfoLevel` was not able to return all the needed information.

```
if (FileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_COMPRESSED) {
    std::cout << "File is compressed.";
}
if (FileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_READONLY) {
    std::cout << "File is a readonly file.";
}
```

I thought there should be a similar thing for file properties something like `GetFilePropertiesExA()`.
But could not find any similar function so far.
Also I was able to get information like Date created, modified and size using `WIN32_FIND_DATA`.

Comment: Look at this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wic/-wic-about-metadata

Comment: @Florent: What about mp3 or xls?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/properties/windows-properties-system

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will read into it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/master/Samples/Win7Samples/winui/shell/appplatform/PropertyEdit) is some sample code from Microsoft for reading/writing file properties. It's using the WinAPI to read the file properties.

You can find a list of available properties [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/win32/properties/props).

Depending on what you want to do, you may also take a look at [these](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/properties/functions-propvarutil) `PROPVARIANT` functions. For example, when you want to store the value of a property into a string.